# How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT by 5 and start from 2000

Tags: oracle

I need to increment id by 5 and start from 2000

```
CREATE TABLE example (
     id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IDENTITY` column as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
     id GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 2000 INCREMENT BY 5),
     name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```